# Google Image publishing guidelines; landing page for each image?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, landing-page, google-image-search

In [Google Image publishing guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) there is a paragraph about landing page for each image:

> Even if your image appears on several pages on your site, consider creating a **standalone landing page for each image**, where you can gather all its related information. If you do this, be sure to provide unique information — such as descriptive titles and captions — on each page. You could also enable comments, discussions, or ratings for each picture.

I am wondering in what scenarios this might be beneficial. If Google indexes the landing page for an image, instead of the article where this image is used; it doesn't seem like a good user experience.

E.g: I do an image search for pancakes; and I visit the page that has this image. I would prefer to be taken to a page about pancakes or pancake recipes; not about the pancake *image*. "Here is an image showing a pancake, it has a width of X and a height of Y. And people like this image (high rating)." Fine; but what about the actual pancake, do people like that?

**So;** in what scenarios might a *standalone landing page for each image* be beneficial?

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be a standalone page for every image that is NOT connected to any article or content...

You should create standalone page just for images used for example as background images or logos...

Then, it doesnt matter what description is showed.

Comment: What would be the benefit of that? I don't expect to get much traffic from my background image.

Comment: That is not benefit...i just explained where should be standalone page. I think this standalone page system is useless. Every image should redirect you where it is posted