# NewsArticle: image required for Article

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, rdfa

I to try to add an Image on my Code , how to tell [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92805/google-image-publishing-guidelines-landing-page-for-each-image) ,because [Google Structured Data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http%3A%2F%2Fhtmlkurss.xyz%2Fwindows8.php) force it... , but every Time I come an error..
My Code;

```
<main vocab="http://schema.org"> 
<article typeof="NewsArticle" lang="en">
 <img property="contentUrl url" src="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" alt="VirtualBox"/>

<header> 
 <h2 property="headline">Wie instaliert Virtual Box in Windows 10</h2>
   <br>
   <p property="description">News item summary goes here.</p>
</header> 

  <span property="name" value="Virtual Box"/>
  <span property="mainEntityOfPage" value="http://google.de"/>
  <span property="datePublished" value="2019-03-07"/>
  <span property="dateModified" value="2019-03-17"/>
  <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
     <span property="name">http://htmlkurss.xyz</span> 
     <span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
    <img property="contentUrl url" src="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" alt="VirtualBox"/></span>
      </span>

  <p property="text">Virtual Box ist eine Virtualisierungssoftware, die viele Betriebessysteme emulieren kann. Sie funktioniert mit Linux , Mac und Windows. Sie hat auch veschiedenene Sprachen für ihre Oberfläche, wie beispielsweise Deutsch, Englisch ,... 
  </p>


  <footer>
  <p property="author" typeof="Person">Autor: <span property="name">http://htmlkurss.xyz</span></p>

  <p>Korrekturen: <span property="editor">Rolf B</span></p>
 </footer> 
</article>
```

I don't know how does it ...

Can Please anyone help me for this Problem , Very Thanks !

**New Edit:**

**unor** tell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069318/schema-org-microdata-image-required-for-article) how to prevent it ,with **hasPart** ..., i does it..
I write on `<article  property="hasPart" typeof="NewsArticle">` , and come not more error , but come a Red  cross , how the Screenshot to show..[image]

Comment: Did you notice (in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/121603/17633) to your other question) that the `span` element can’t have a `value` attribute?  And here is another error: you can’t self-close it either, it needs a `</span>`.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include in your RDFa snippet how you tried to add `image`?

Comment: I will to do similar how under as Logo . <img property="contentUrl url" src="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" alt="VirtualBox"/>  , ...because  i to reaided it is similar as Logo , when anyone not will it to display ..

Comment: "Did you notice (in my answer to your other question) that the span element can’t have a value attribute?" , you mean with content=" "

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show this (how you add `image`). The comments are not the right place to include the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my Problem....

My Problem was on third Line;

```
<img property="contentUrl url" src="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" alt="VirtualBox"/>
```

I loose it , and add it...

```
<meta img property="image" src="/image/me.jpg">
```

Now come not a Warning !

Comment: Note that you must use `link` instead of `meta` (if the value is a URL): `<link property="image" href="/image/me.jpg">`